# Installing a font package in TeX-Live

Tags: fonts, packages, installing, texlive

I cannot make *fourier* and other font packages to work on TeX-Live on Mac OS.  I have installed *fourier* package and tried `updmap-sys` and `mktexlsr` terminal commands in different combinations.  Still the following example does not compile:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
$0$
\end{document}
```

I get:

> pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file futr8r): Font futr8r at 552 not found

My question: what is the proper way to install a font package in TeX Live?  For example, what should i have done to install *fourier* package, in addition to installing it with *TeX Live Utility*?  Can i re-install it?

---

I have tried to reinstall or remove *fourier* with *TeX Live Utility*.  Reinstallation claims to succeed, but does not fix the package.  Removal does not work, i get the following log messages:

```
2013-11-10 12:10:24 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController removePackagesWithNames:force:][1376]    Beginning removal of
(
    fourier
)
2013-11-10 12:10:24 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation main][1376]   Checking code signature before running tlu_ipctask as root…
2013-11-10 12:10:24 +0000 Notice /usr/bin/codesign[1376]    /Applications/Custom/TeX Front Ends/TeX Live Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/tlu_ipctask: valid on disk
/Applications/Custom/TeX Front Ends/TeX Live Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/tlu_ipctask: satisfies its Designated Requirement
2013-11-10 12:10:24 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation main][1376]   Signature was valid, okay to run tlu_ipctask
2013-11-10 12:10:32 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation main][1376]   Invoking privileged task via AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges
2013-11-10 12:10:32 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[4080]  dropped privileges to user nobody
2013-11-10 12:10:33 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation setWrapperPID:][1376] tlu_ipctask checking in:  tlu_ipctask pid = 4080
2013-11-10 12:10:33 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation setUnderlyingPID:][1376]  tlu_ipctask checking in: pid = 4081 (/usr/texbin/tlmgr remove fourier)
2013-11-10 12:10:33 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[4080]  tlu_ipctask: child HOME = '/var/root'
2013-11-10 12:10:33 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[4080]  tlu_ipctask: current HOME = '/var/empty'
2013-11-10 12:10:34 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[4080]  tlmgr: removing package fourier
2013-11-10 12:10:34 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[4080]  tlmgr: ultimately removed these packages: fourier
2013-11-10 12:10:34 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[4080]  tlmgr: package log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
2013-11-10 12:10:34 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[4080]  running mktexlsr ...
2013-11-10 12:10:35 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[4080]  done running mktexlsr.
2013-11-10 12:10:35 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[4080]  running updmap-sys ...
2013-11-10 12:10:40 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[4080]  done running updmap-sys.
2013-11-10 12:10:40 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][1376] kqueue noted that pid 4081 exited (/usr/texbin/tlmgr remove fourier)
2013-11-10 12:10:40 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[4080]  child process pid = 4081 exited
2013-11-10 12:10:41 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[4080]  exit status of pid = 4081 was 0
2013-11-10 12:10:41 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][1376] waitpid returned 4080, WIFEXITED(0) = 1, errno = 17 (File exists)
2013-11-10 12:10:41 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][1376] kqueue noted that tlu_ipctask (pid = 4080) exited with status 0
2013-11-10 12:10:41 +0000 Notice -[TLMRemoveOperation main][1376]   ERROR: failed to remove packages {(
    fourier
)} (requested removal of (
    fourier
))
```

---

I experimented further: i removed and reinstalled the whole TeX Live distribution, installed updates and *fourier* package.  I tried to remove it right away, and the removal failed.  I reinstalled it, and tried to compile my test file, and the compilation failed with a different error:

> pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file putr8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font 
>   file for reading

Comment: Why are you doing it manually? If you installed MacTeX you already have `fourier`.

Comment: I have not installed complete MacTeX (it is huge).  I am not doing it manually: i used TeX Live Utility, but as it did not work, i tried some terminal commands.

Comment: I know it is huge, but what you are trying to do seems to be even worse... Seriously, consider a full installation of MacTeX.

Comment: Siminore, your comment is unhelpful.  What i am doing is not worse, i am simply choosing packages that i need.  If everyone was doing like me, maybe the package system would have worked better.

Comment: I used to run on my Macs with the minimal package, and try to install things as I needed them, but it was never very satisfactory.  Since TexLive 2012, I run with a complete installation.  It *is* huge, and it can take a long time to download, but trust us: it is worth it!  The time it will take you to download is less than the time you will spend trying to fix things that don't work with the minimal approach.

Comment: The error means that you didn't enabled the map file.  So either you used updmap-sys incorrectly or you have local map files and need to run updmap.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, can you tell me please how to use the commands correctly?  I did `sudo updmap-sys --syncwithtrees`.  I should not normally have local map files, whatever they are.  If i have them, can i delete them?

Comment: I can't help asking this to @Siminore: when you install Ubuntu, to you install all Ubuntu packages with it?  When you install Windows, do you install all Windows applications with it?

Comment: Listen @Alexey: my suggestion was and is: install the complete MacTeX 2013. Don't you want to? Well, then solve your problems if you can.

Answer (score 4):

I recently encountered a very similar error message in Windows 7 MiKTeX 2.9. The solution was to simply run `udpmap.exe` as administrator. The program is located in:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\
```

Comment: And where would this be found on a Mac? Given that the OP was after a Mac OS solution.

Comment: Not helpful for the OP, but this worked for me on Windows

Answer (score 2):

Installing `utopia` package fixed the problem.